# Android SMS: group by its thread id

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am implementing a SMS App, till now i achieved to get all the messages(sent, received, drafts) with its contact number, thread id, contact id, date, type.

Here is my code:

```
Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
        Cursor cursor = _context.getContentResolver().query(
                mSmsinboxQueryUri,
                new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "date", "body",
                        "type" }, null, null, null);

        String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "thread_id", "date",
                "body", "type" };
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                String address = null, date = null, msg = null, type = null, threadId = null;

                address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
                threadId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
                date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
                msg = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
                type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[4]));

                Log.e("SMS-inbox", "\nTHREAD_ID: "
                        + threadId + "\nNUMBER: " + address + "\nTIME: " + date + "\nMESSAGE: " + msg + "\nTYPE: " + type);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, I need to separate these messages by thread id (messages with same thread id). How can I best achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: You might be looking for 'GROUP BY' in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not save those strings seperatly in the first place.

What I would do is a class like:

```
public class SmsMsg {
    private String address = null;
    private String threadId = null;
    private String date = null;
    private String msg = null;
    private String type = null;

    //c'tor
    public SmsMsg(Cursor cursor) {
       this.address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
       this.threadId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("thread_id"));
       this.date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
       this.msg = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
       this.type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")); 
    }
}
```

now you can instantiate an object of `SmsMsg` in your while-loop as long `cursor.moveToNext()` is `true` and add it to a `List` of your choice.

You now could copy all messages of a desired `threadId` to a different `List` and sort it by date for example. That depends on what you want do do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes i will follow this creating a ArrayList<SmsMsg>, now first i need to get all the thread_id's to one array and then for each id i need to create a new ArrayList<SmsMsg>.

Could you please elaborate on sorting by date.

Comment: Is this the right way am approaching or would you please suggest me a resource or reference source for a messaging App with features like listing all messages by conversation, deleting a message, delete a conversation etc..

Comment: save the Id's to a List aswell. With all the functionality you will get, you also avoid Null-Pointer Exceptions, which could happen easily.

Comment: You have to decide what you want to do. You *could* load everything in a big huge List<SmsMsg> and then sort out to smaller "thread"-lists, *or* you could check in the while-loop if you are interested in that very message (judged by threaId for example) and only add it if it meets your criteria. For this approach you have do run over all messages and just grab the threadIds beforehand.

Comment: for sort by date you have to read about custom comparators (http://www.javabeat.net/2007/09/sorting-custom-types-in-java/) since date is a String-object and therefore not really good comparable, you will have to parse it to a DateTime-object (if I recall correctly).

Comment: *OF COURSE* you could parse it directly in the c'tor of your SmsMsg-Class and save some trouble later.

Comment: Thanks for the help, am accepting this answer. Still lot do to make this app fully functional.

I want to list all the recent chats in a list view and on click open the conversation. On send new message, start new conversation update the database. please provide me any references or sample source code...

Comment: Sorry I don't have any good sources (not even bad ones). But don't hesitate to ask a question on SO. I am sure somebody knows an answer, or at least can point to it.